# Using Elliptic Curve Key Pair on Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, sign, elliptic-curve

I need to use an Elliptic Curve Key pair on Android to sign and verify Strings. I use following code to generate the Key Pair

```
val parameterSpec = ECNamedCurveTable.getParameterSpec("secp160r1")

fun genKeyPair(): KeyPair{
    val keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(
            "EC", "SC")
    keyPairGenerator.initialize(parameterSpec, SecureRandom())
    val keyPair: KeyPair = keyPairGenerator.genKeyPair()
    return keyPair
}
```

The App is written in Kotlin but I am happy about any Java-related answer too.
Does somebody know where I can find good resources or code examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find good documentation from the Android developer website: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore#kotlin
There are examples of how to generate, store in the Keystore, Sign and verify data.

**EDITED**

For example, to create a KeyPair

```
val kpg: KeyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_EC,
    "AndroidKeyStore")
val parameterSpec: KeyGenParameterSpec = KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder("alias",
    KeyProperties.PURPOSE_SIGN).run {
    setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256)
    build()
    }
kpg.initialize(parameterSpec)
val keyPair = kpg.generateKeyPair()
```

If you want to share your public key to a server

```
val pubKey = keyPair.public
val pubKeyString = String(Base64.encode(pubKey.encoded, 0))
```

Sign Data

```
val signature: ByteArray = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withECDSA").run {
    initSign(privKey)
    update(data)
    sign()
    }
```

Verify Data

```
val valid: Boolean = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withECDSA").run {
    initVerify(pubKey)
    update(data)
    verify(signature)
    }
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21540714)

Comment: Hi @Pino, thanks for your feedback. I've already added some examples of the question. I hope it can help

Comment: here result is coming : android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreECPublicKey@f90e9bc76,how to get encoded by Hexcode

Comment: what about the private key in the string ?